# Exception: Error happened when building Observer, but it was captured since disableErrorBoundaries==true

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx, observer-pattern, provider

I am returning below widget in my build method of StatefulWidget class in flutter app:

```
return Stack(
  children: [
    Observer(
      builder: (context) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              _dashboardStore.showFirstPageLoading == false
                  ? _buildDashboardTableDataWidgets()
                  : Container(),
              _dashboardStore.showFirstPageLoading == false
                  ? _buildFactAndFigureWidget()
                  : Container(),
              //_showSearchAndSummaryList(),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
    _showRetryButton(),
    _showLoader()
  ],
);
```

You can notice that I am using **Observer** and using **mobx** state management in flutter. Here, **_dashboardStore** is the class which with mixin **Store** and initialized as below:

```
_dashboardStore = Provider.of<DashboardStore>(context, listen: false);
```

In my above Widget I am using below observable fields which is their inside DashboardStore as:

```
@observable
  DashboardTableDataRes? dashboardTableDataRes;

  @observable
  FactAndFigureDataRes? dashboardFactAndFigureRes;
```

But I am getting below exception while running the app:

> The following _Exception was thrown building Observer(dirty):
> Exception: Error happened when building Observer, but it was captured
> since disableErrorBoundaries==true
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:    Observer
> Observer:file:///home/growexx/StudioProjects/flutter-mobile-app/lib/ui/dashboard/dashboard_view.dart:92:9

Below is the dependency I am using in **pubspec.yaml** file:

```
mobx: ^2.0.1
  flutter_mobx: ^2.0.0
  provider: ^6.0.0
```

and below are the dev dependencies:

```
  mobx_codegen: ^2.0.1+3
  build_runner: ^2.0.3
```

What am I doing wrong here or What might be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your direct return of singleChildScrollView without first ensuring **null safety** may be the problem.

So, you can try the below method to avoid this error:

```
Observer(
  builder: (context) {
    // check for null safety first
    if (_dashboardStore.dashboardTableDataRes == null && 
        _dashboardStore.dashboardFactAndFigureRes == null) {
     return Container(); // Return loading or any Other error widget you want
    }

    // Continue to build your UI without null data
    // your widget
    return SingleChildScrollView(
    );
  },
),
```

Also, I'm assuming `_dashboardStore.showFirstPageLoading == false` in your store (controller) you initialized with the default value.

If not, then also try null safe for `_dashboardStore.showFirstPageLoading == false` also and return loading or something you want in your code.